# How to create a yellow hint with Java swt?

Tags: java, swt, jface, hint

Can someone explain me something? How can I create a yellow hint/notification with Java swt?

I want that popup a small notice when I move over a cell in a table. Something like this:

[image]

This is my Java-Code:

```
protected void checkAction() throws Exception {

    //Erstellen einer neuen Shell
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(280, 300);
    shell.setText("Testtabelle");

    //Erstellen einer neuen Tabelle
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    //Einlesen der Überschriften und Vergabe der Namen
    String[] titles = {"Element", "Stage", "Type", "Generate-User", "Change-User" }; 
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
      column.setText(titles[i]);
    }

    // Inhalte hinzufügen
    final int count = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText(0, "Test "+i);
      item.setText(1, ""+(i+1));
      item.setText(2, "Testtype");
      item.setText(3, "562910");
      item.setText(4, "423424");
    }

   // Tabelle und Shell Packen  
   for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }
    table.setSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, 200));
    shell.pack();

    //MouseListener

    table.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
          Rectangle clientArea = table.getClientArea();
          Point pt = new Point(event.x, event.y);
          int index = table.getTopIndex();
      //    System.out.println("TopIndex: "+index);
          while (index < table.getItemCount()) {
            boolean visible = false;
            TableItem item = table.getItem(index);
            for (int i = 0; i < (table.getItemCount()+1); i++) {
              Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(i);
              if (rect.contains(pt)) {
                String selected = table.getItem(index).getText(i);

                if (selected.equals("562910")){
                    String real = "Jonas";
                    System.out.println(real);

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Ausgewählt: "+selected);    
                }

              }
              if (!visible && rect.intersects(clientArea)) {
                visible = true;
              }
            } 
            if (!visible)
              return;
            index++;
          }
        }
      });


    // Shell öffnen
      shell.open();



}
```

Comment: Awt components are heavyweight in nature. You can use Swing component to create such kind of labels.

Comment: thank u for your answer. oh sorry. i made a mistake. i mean swt. in my project i only can use swt and not swing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just SWT use the code in [SWT Snippet 125](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet125.java).

If you can use JFace then `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` is rather easier.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. now i have the problem that it only works in the first column and not in the other. is there a command to select the columns i want this feature ?

Comment: Do you mean it always shows the first column text or something else?

Comment: I have a table with 4 columns. When i move over a cell in the column 2-4 the tooltip only appears in the first column. i want that the tooltips appears for an inviduell column with a specifical titel

Comment: I think you would have to loop through the columns using `TableItem.getBounds(columnIndex)` to find the column the mouse is in and then use the column text and bounds for the tooltip.

Comment: can u say me where i must add the loop ? i have started a entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727182/tooltip-in-other-colums-with-java-swt

Answer (score -1):

You should start using jface `TableViewer`. To create table column, you will use `TableViewerColumn`.

For each column, add `CellLabelProvider` which has `getToolTipXXX()` methods.

```
TableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(CellLabelProvider)
```

here is good article to start with

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html